# ng-repeat track by is not working: slow and still generating $$hashKey

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-track-by

I have an ng-repeat set up like so:

```
ng-repeat="article in main[main.mode].primary | orderBy: main[main.mode].primary.filter.order
track by article.url"
```

`main[main.mode].primary` is an array and …`.filter.order` is a string.

According to [this blog post](http://www.codelord.net/2014/04/15/improving-ng-repeat-performance-with-track-by/)

> Behind the scenes ngRepeat adds a $$hashKey property to each task to keep track of it. If you replace the original tasks with new tasks objects from the server, even if those are in fact totally identical to your original tasks, they won’t have the $$hashKey property and so ngRepeat won’t know they represent the same elements.

Regenerating the list is a very common task and the app is hanging for over a second, hence my interest in track by. According to the many questions and docs I've looked at, I've used the correct syntax to both order and track an array. From [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

> item in items | filter:searchText track by item.id is a pattern that might be used to apply a filter to items in conjunction with a tracking expression.

Why isn't track by being implemented? I'm running angular 1.3.11.

**Edit**
It doesn't even work if I remove the orderBy argument

```
ng-repeat="article in main[main.mode].primary track by article.url"
```

Comment: try "article in (main[main.mode].primary | orderBy: main[main.mode].primary.filter.order)
track by article.url"

Comment: No luck. It actually doesn't work whether I use the orderBy argument or not.

Comment: is main[main.mode].primary  an array or an object?

Comment: Well, I was abusing the JS language a bit it seems by adding named properties to an array (this works because arrays are objects), but you were right to pinpoint that as the problem. I've spun out the named props into separate objects and `track by` is now working. The performance still isn't what I had hoped it would be, and I'll look into other ways to improve performance, but it's much better. Thanks for the help. I would be happy to accept an answer if you feel like posting one (i.e. rephrasing the above question as a statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the Angular Documentation orderBy only works on arrays  so if you are iterating over an object you are not going to be able to use it unless you convert your object into an array

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

there are other ways you can handle this either implementing your own filter or just by transforming your object into an array of objects with key value properties. something like

```
var narr=[]
angular.forEach(object,function(k,v){
  narr.push({key:v,value:v})
})
```

and now narr is an array ready to be sorted by either key or value using orderBy